Scraping multiple pages using Puppeteer
I can scrape the 1st page but whenever it goes to 2nd page it always gives me error

TimeoutError: Navigation timeout of 30000 ms exceeded

const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra")
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth")

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());


async function scrapeEpisode(page){
  const EpisodesOnPage = await page.evaluate(() =>
    Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div.wr-subject")).map(compact => ({
      title: compact.innerText.trim(),
      link: compact.querySelector("a").href
    }))
  );
  console.log(EpisodesOnPage);
}

(async () => {
  const callURL = async url => {
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    console.log(url);
    await page.goto(url, {'timeout': 10000, 'waitUntil':'load'})
    await page.waitForSelector('#viewcomment')
    await scrapeEpisode(page)

    let lastPageReached = false
    let nextPageNumber = 1
    while (!lastPageReached){
      const endPage = await page.$('.wr-none')
      if (endPage) {
        console.log('No more pages. Exiting.')
        lastPageReached = true;
      } else {
          // const nextPageNumber = parseInt(url.match(/spage=(\d+)$/)[1], 10) + 1
          // const nextUrl = url + `&spage=${nextPageNumber}`
          nextPageNumber++
          const nextUrl = url + '&spage=' + nextPageNumber
          console.log(nextUrl)
          // const URL = page.nextUrl();
          console.log('visit page')
          // await page.goto(nextUrl, {'timeout': 50000, 'waitUntil':'load'})
          await page.goto(nextUrl)
          console.log('wait for selector')
          await page.waitForSelector('#viewcomment')
          console.log('scraping data...')
          await scrapeEpisode.concat(page)
          // return EpisodesOnPage.concat(await scrapeEpisode(nextUrl))
      }
    }
  }

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    targetFilter: (target) => target.type() !== "other",
  });
  var url = 'https://booktoki460.com/novel/222?page=2&book=%EC%9D%BC%EB%B0%98%EC%86%8C%EC%84%A4'
  const Episodes = await callURL(url);
  console.log(Episodes);
  
})();

I am expecting to scrape next pages.
What's happening is it visit's the 2nd page but but doesn't continue and just timeout.

await scrapeEpisode.concat(page) that looks very wrong.. can't say that's the only problem but surely it's one

Even visiting this as a human, I'm hit with a captcha--maybe it's a regional thing, but I don't see how you're defeating that in this code.

i don't have issues with the captcha and cloudflare i can visit it normally with stealth but sometimes u got the captcha thing and just click it manually and it will proceed.
